# How to integate Git with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am trying to add Git support in IntelliJ IDEA. I have seen on youtube video people had git in this dialog. But for me, it is missing. Please let me know how can I add git in IntelliJ version 2018.1.

[image]

Also, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#put-existing-project-under-Git says 2 options about git. For me, both are missing. Also, I tied to found a suitable plugin, I found one at one at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3033-git-integration . It says not copatible version.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [their guide on using git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html)?

Comment: yes, I found it. But if you click the inner link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#put-existing-project-under-Git . It mentions VCS | Enable Version Control Integration or VCS | Import into Version Control | Create Git Repository. For me, both are missing. Please check the updated question. I must be missing some plugin or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found for me TFS Integration and Git Integration both enable. When I uninstalled the TFS Integration? Then the git features seem to be enabled. So it works by this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable Version control Integration list will only contains the version control systems for which the corresponding plugins are currently enabled

So make sure that you have installed the 'Git Integration' plugin and it's enabled. You can check that in Settings/Plugins (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and select plugins and search for Git.

Install the plugin if not installed and you will be able see in the list
[image]